# Pre checking/selecting radio button in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a page with radio button which need to be prefilled on page load ...my code works perfectly in firefox , IE8 and IE7 in IE8 but when I am trying IE7 pure environment ...radio button is not prefilled whereas disable the radio works perfectly ....
   any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

edit1: code

```
main.disable = function($cntrl, flag){
    if($cntrl.attr('type')=== "radio"){
       var ctrls = document.getElementByName($cntrl.attr('name'));
       for(var idx = 0 ; idx < ctrls.length; idx++){
            ctrls[idx].disabled = flag;
      }
   else{
       $cntrl.disabled = flag;
}
};
main.getControlById = function(id, context){
  if(id.search("{") > 0){
    id = main.fillTem(id, context);
}

return $(document.getElementById(id));
};

behave.addRule("abc","Enable/disable aa", function(){
var $ab = main.getControlById(a.ab, this);

        if( supp !== undefined && supp !== null){
            if(supp.ab === 'A' || supp.A === 'N'){
               main.disable($ab, false);
}
else{
   main.disable($ab, false);
}
}

else{
main.disable($ab, false);
}
});
```

Comment: You will need to post some code....

Answer (score 2):

It's the same problem I'm having right now: I create a list for radio buttons dynamically, and in Internet Explorer 7 you can't select them.

What I found is it's not a problem related to jQuery: even creating the elements in pure JavaScript yields non working inputs.

If you want your dynamic radio inputs to work in IE7 you must declare them in a single line.

This will not work in IE <= 7:

```
var input = $("<input />");
input.attr("id", answers[index].id);
input.attr("type", "radio");
input.attr("name", "answer");
input.val(answers[index].value);
```

Instead use this code:

```
var input = $("<input id='" + answers[index].id + "' type='radio' name='answer' value='" + answers[index].value + "'></input>");
```

Watch out for the `</input>`, you can't use the self closing tag (`/>`).

Comment: you are caching the entire thing ...which is good for optimization...i resolve the issue by binding the controls(like radio, text ) after loading the page ...basically its problem with IE7 slow rendering ...anyways thanks for the advice....

Comment: The radio buttons I create are created when the user performs a choice clicking on another button, so the page is already loaded and ready (it doesn't matter how long I wait to click). If you managed to fix it in another way can you post a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're running your code before the page has finished rendering. IE7 is slower at rendering pages than IE8.

If you JS code is before your HTML and you're not using `$(document).ready(function() { .... })` to invoke it then the cart is before the horse.

Comment: thanks! but I already wrap is around .ready() but no luck ...wasted hell lot of time on that ...i know its rendering problem but did n't find a proper solution...